# Не поднимается контейнер docker

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, build, dockerfile

прописываю docker run -d -p 80:80 test4 и появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS builder


LABEL version ="1.0"



RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y systemd && \
    apt-get install -y libpcre3 && \
    apt-get install -y libpcre3-dev && \
    apt-get install -y zlib1g && \
    apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev
 
 
 
 
WORKDIR /builddir/

COPY ./nginx-1.23.1 /builddir/

ADD scriptbuild /builddir/nginx-1.23.1

        



FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /dirbuild/

COPY --from=builder /builddir/nginx-1.23.1/ /dirbuild/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["./scriptbuild"]

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off"]
```

Содержимое scriptbuild

```
#!/bin/bash
./configure --sbin-path=/builddir/nginx-1.23.1 --conf-path=/builddir/nginx-1.23.1/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/ndinx.pid --with-http_ssl_module

make

make install
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `CMD ["./scriptbuild"]` нужно использовать `RUN`, тогда у вас `nginx` будет собран при сборке образа.

В `Dockerfile` может быть только одна `CMD` команда (да их можно написать две, но выполняться будет только последняя), которая будет выполняться при запуске контейнера.

[Документация CMD](https://CMD%20%5B%22./scriptbuild%22%5D)

Например `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS builder
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libgd-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev uuid-dev wget
RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.23.1.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf nginx-1.23.1.tar.gz
WORKDIR /nginx-1.23.1
RUN mkdir -p /builddir
RUN ./configure --sbin-path=/builddir --conf-path=/builddir/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/ndinx.pid --with-http_ssl_module && \
    make && \
    make install

FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx && \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/nginx
WORKDIR /builddir
COPY --from=builder /builddir/ /builddir/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/builddir/nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

- вы пытаетесь использовать multi-stage build, но не правильно, такой подход подразумевает, что у вас один stage это сборка `nginx` + все его зависимости, в второй - это уже непосредственно готовый образу для запауска.
- если вы хотиде запускать на `alpine`, то лучше и собирать на нем, т.к. у `ubuntu` и `alpine` разные версии `libc` (стандартрная библиотека) и когда собирается программа из исходником, она часто линкуется с конкретной версией, которая стоит в системе.
- `RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx && mkdir -p /usr/local/nginx` не обязательно, но тогда нужно поменять параметры в `./configure`.
- сейчас исходный код `nginx` скачивается при сборке, он не должен лежать рядом с `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, но я не до конца понимаю как реализовать, если сильно не затруднит, не могли бы вы подсказать? Я только недавно начинал изучать docker)
В перенёс скрипт в builder, выглядит примерно так:
ADD scriptbuild /builddir/
RUN [ "./scriptbuild " ]
Во втором FROM:
 COPY --from=builder /builddir/* /dirbuild/
 CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off"]
 Но ошибка остаётся

Comment: @Fludd обновил ответ

Comment: Я использовал alpine потому что хотел сильно облегчить образ. Теперь я стал умнее). Спасибо